# randomForest and variable importance bug?

Tags: r, random-forest, importance

I dont get the difference between the `rfobject$importance` and `importance(rfobject)` in the MeanDecreaseAccuracy column.

Example:

```
> data("iris")
> fit <- randomForest(Species~., data=iris, importance=TRUE)
> fit$importance
                  setosa  versicolor   virginica MeanDecreaseAccuracy MeanDecreaseGini
Sepal.Length 0.027078501 0.019418330 0.040497602           0.02898837         9.173648
Sepal.Width  0.008553449 0.001962036 0.006951771           0.00575489         2.472105
Petal.Length 0.313303381 0.291818815 0.280981959           0.29216790        41.284869
Petal.Width  0.349686983 0.318527008 0.270975757           0.31054451        46.323415
> importance(fit)
               setosa versicolor virginica MeanDecreaseAccuracy MeanDecreaseGini
Sepal.Length 1.277324   1.632586  1.758101            1.2233029         9.173648
Sepal.Width  1.007943   0.252736  1.014141            0.6293145         2.472105
Petal.Length 3.685513   4.434083  4.133621            2.5139980        41.284869
Petal.Width  3.896375   4.421567  4.385642            2.5371353        46.323415
>
```

I get different MeanDecreaseAccuracy values but have the same order for the importance Variables (for `fit$importance` as well as for `importance(fit)`):

1. Petal.Width
2. Petal.Length
3. Sepal.Length
4. Sepal.Width

But in other datasets I sometimes get different orders. Can someone explain what is happening here?  Is this possibly a bug?

---

**Edit** (in response to [Martin O'Leary](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/35045/930))

Okay Thanks! I noticed something else.

Taking a Look at the `rfcv()` function i noticed the line:

```
impvar <- (1:p)[order(all.rf$importance[, 1], decreasing = TRUE)]
```

with this line we choose the first column of `all.rf$importance` which gives us the order of the class-specific (for the **first factor**) measures computed as mean descrease in accuracy only. This has not always the same order as the mean descrease in accuracy over all classes (`MeanDecreaseAccuracy`). Wouldn't it be better choosing either the `MeanDecreaseAccuracy` or `MeanDecreaseGini` column, or better using the `importance()`-function for the scaled values?
So we would have a sequentially reduced number of predictors ranked by variable importance (over all classes) and not only ranked by variable importance for the first class.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, this isn't a bug. The values given in `fit$importance` are unscaled, while the values given by `importance(fit)` are expressed in terms of standard deviations (as given by `fit$importanceSD`). This is usually a more meaningful measure. If you want the "raw" values, you can use `importance(fit, scale=FALSE)`.

In general, it's a very bad idea to rely on the internal details of a fit object, when there's an extractor function provided. There are no guarantees as to the contents of `fit$importance` - they could change drastically from version to version without notice. You should always use the extractor function when it's provided.

---

**Edit:** Yes, that line in `rfcv()` does look like a bug, or at least unintended behaviour. It's actually quite a good example of why you shouldn't rely on the contents of things like `fit$importance`. If the fit is for a regression forest, the first column of `fit$importance` is `%IncMSE`, equivalent to `importance(fit, type=1)`. However, this doesn't hold in the classification case, where you have extra columns for each factor level.